# Third Normal Form DB

Tags: database, database-design

I have a table with these columns:

```
person_id, name, age
```

`person_id` is the primary key.

Does `age` depend on both `name` and `person_id`, or only depends on `person_id`?

If I want it to the 3NF should I decompose it into two tables?

Comment: Does the age change, if you rename yourself from "Joe" to "Tim" ?

Comment: I think no, good explanation, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only depends on person_id so you don't need to decompose the table.

And if name is an alternate key (that would be very strange) you could say that name is unique and again, you wouln't need to decompose your table.